# Pandas dataframe, how to replace part of the row based on the value from other rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which looks like below,

```
     position| top   |   mid   |  bottom |
ID  |  result| value |   value |   value | 
001 |   pass | 315.6 |   315.4 |   223.3 |
002 |   pass | 315.5 |   315.3 |   221.2 |
003 |   pass | 315.4 |   315.4 |   222.8 |
004 |   fail | 315.9 |   315.1 |   223.1 |
005 |   pass | 315.4 |   315.2 |   222.4 |
```

and I want the data format to be

```
ID  |  result| top   |   mid   |  bottom | 
001 |   pass | 315.6 |   315.4 |   223.3 |
002 |   pass | 315.5 |   315.3 |   221.2 |
003 |   pass | 315.4 |   315.4 |   222.8 |
004 |   fail | 315.9 |   315.1 |   223.1 |
005 |   pass | 315.4 |   315.2 |   222.4 |
```

Is there any pretty way to achieve that ? I only think about the way of storing the three values of position into a list. Then, to remove the first row and to rename the column name based on the value from the list of position.  Somehow, I think it should a better way to do that?

P.s. Actually the number of columns of position will have more than three columns, and I just simplified the dataset for easily understanding.   Thanks

Comment: You can pd.rename.

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ? There is `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: df.columns will be *** Index(['Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2',  'P-1', 'P-2', 'P-3' , ..., 'P-50'])  *** originally

And, no index at first

Comment: @Jammy - If use `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0,1])` (added `header=[0,1]`) what is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: It would be 
MultiIndex([('Unnamed:0_level_0', 'ID'),
                     ('Unnamed:1_level_0', 'result'),
                     ('P-1', 'Value'),
                     ('P-2', 'Value'),
                      ('P-3', 'Value'),
                       ....
                      .....
                      ('P-50', 'Value')],
                      )

Comment: Sorry for a bit typo before. It should be Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1', 'P-1', 'P-2', 'P-3' , ..., 'P-50'])

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
d1 = {'position':''}
d2 = {'value':''}

df = df.rename(columns=d1, level=0).rename(columns=d2, level=1)

df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
```